# Spring batch, errorr when adding new reader

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I'm working on projet spring batch simple process read, process write to csv file. There are already many readers ans sql scripts in this projet. The problem when i add new reader and sql script and i start the batch, i got an error . However, when i use the new reader to and old script sql, it works and the same thing if I use an existing reader to select the new sql script, it works fine but not i use both.
These are the elements:

```
/** 
* Reader
*/
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class BillDefaultReader extends AbstractBillReader {

    public BillDEfaultReader(final DataSource dataSource) throws IOException {
        super(dataSource);
        this.setPreparedStatementSetter(s -> s.setString(1, "DEFAULT"));
    }

    @Override
    protected String getSqlPath() {
        return "/sql/get_script1.sql"; -> SQL 
    }

}

// The job config 

 @Bean
public Job batchExJob(final Step batchExStep, final ReportGeneratorJobListener reportGeneratorJobListener) {
    return this.jobs.get("batchExJob").start(batchExStep).listener(reportGeneratorJobListener).build();
}

@Bean
public Step batchExStep(final ItemReader<BillTransmissionDTO> compositeBillReader,
                        final ItemProcessor<BillTransmissionDTO, BillTransmissionDTO> compositeProcessor,
                        final ItemWriter<BillTransmissionDTO> billTransmissionWriter) {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("batchExStep").<BillTransmissionDTO, BillTransmissionDTO>chunk(this.commitInterval).reader(compositeBillReader)
                                                                                                                                .processor(compositeProcessor)
                                                                                                                                .writer(billTransmissionWriter)
                                                                                                                                .faultTolerant()
                                                                                                                                .skipPolicy(this::skipExceptionsPolicy)
                                                                                                                                .build();
}

@StepScope
@Bean
public ItemProcessor<BillTransmissionDTO, BillTransmissionDTO> compositeProcessor(final IntegrateBillProcessor integrateBillProcessor,
                                                                                        final InitialisationPayEndowmentProcessor initialisationPaiementDotationProcessor) {
    final CompositeItemProcessor<BillTransmissionDTO, BillTransmissionDTO> processor = new CompositeItemProcessor<>();
    processor.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(integrateBillProcessor, initializePaiementEndowmentProcessor));
    return processor;
}
```

**So this is a part of code (it's translated), This is the same process and same code for all readers and sql , any idea please?**

Thank you!

Comment: I forgot to put the error message: ERROR | AbstractStep | Encountered an error executing step batchExStep in job batchExJob   org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
.... Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30018ms.

Comment: attach the error message to the question by editing it, rather than adding a comment

Comment: Looks like spring is not able to connect to Database. Is your database up and running. Could you try to connect it from terminal or from UI. Also try increasing your connection pool size.

Comment: @sujay mohan, yes indeed it was beacause the pool size. Thank you !